# Application continue to perform network operation after entering to the background?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsurlconnection, uiapplicationdelegate

I was looking into a debug file my application creates while running and saw a strange behavior:
The application uses `NSURLConnction` to retrieve some data from a server. The connection was started and then the user moved application to the background probable by pressing the home button (`application:willResignActive` and `application:didEnterBackground` methods were called).
I could see that the connection was handled in my code after `application:didEnterBackground` was called. (The `connectionDidFinishLoading` of `NSURLConnection` delegate was called after `application:didEnterBackground`). In the implementation of `connectionDidFinishLoading` I perform some operations, but at this point application was probable suspended and the code wasn't called.
Then after almost 12 hours user launched application again (it wasn't terminated, but only was in the background) and the code continued running from the same point it stopped, even before `application:willEnterForeground` and `application:didBecomeActive` were called).
Does it make scenes?
The part of code running before application entered to the foreground changed my application internal state and cause to strange behavior.

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

after you receive `application:didEnterBackground` you have about 5 seconds to do the finishing stuff, after which your application is no longer being scheduled on the cpu.

In your case, the best solution is to announce the start of background work via `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` and finish the download and related tasks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The connection is very short, and ended before the 5 seconds limitation of application:didEnterBackground. I can see in the debug file that that didEnterBackground is called and then after few miliseconds the connection was ended (didFinishLoading was called)